custom error page not rendered by nginx ingress controller via helm
I have followed instructions from how-to-customize-error-pages-served-via-the-default-backend-of-an-nginx-ingress
my setup is as follows
Docker Desktop version: 4.34.2 with kubernetes v1.30.2
I have downloaded helm chart locally from nginx ingress controller for helm
my default backend's default settings in values.yaml are as follows
defaultBackend:
  enabled: True
  name: defaultbackend
  image:
    # registry: registry.k8s.io
    image: defaultbackend-amd64
    tag: "1.5"

I'm mounting volume from configmap under "extra" settings for the backend configuration
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: custom-error-pages
      mountPath: /tmp

  extraVolumes:
    - name: custom-error-pages
      configMap:
        name: custom-error-pages
        items:
        - key: "404.html"
          path: "404.html"
        - key: "503.html"
          path: "503.html"

  extraConfigMaps:
   - name: custom-error-pages
     data:
      404.html: "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n  <head><title>404 PAGE IS NOT FOUND</title></head>\r\n
        \ <body>PAGE IS NOT FOUND 404</body>\r\n</html>"
      503.html: "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n  <head><title>503 PAGE IS NOT FOUND</title></head>\r\n
        \ <body>PAGE IS NOT FOUND 503</body>\r\n</html>"

it deploys ingress controller and backend pod but it still doesnt render my custom 404.html page.
can someone advise why it still presents default 404 not found page?
Testing method:
I have deployed a test app with service expose using Nodeport option. I can access it find as http://localhost:31641 but when i change it to http://localhost/dummy:31641, I expect my custom 404.html not the default one
another issue is that i cant sh into backend pod so cant verify if the extravolume mounted correctly from extraconfigmap but i have tested mounting it in a simple nginx image and it worked find so I'm assuming thats happening here as well.
PS C:\> kubectl exec -it nginx-artifact-ingress-nginx-defaultbackend-5bccd7cc98-gnszf -n nginx-artifact -- sh
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126

